# Issues with reproducing equation using the integral function in R

Tags: r, derivative, integral

I am reading the following paper: https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/STK9190/v18/hjort-petrone-final.pdf
and am trying to reproduce Figure 1 (currently just the left side). The left side of plot used equation 2 on page 3, i.e.,

[image]

which I have coded up in R as follows:

```
# Define the function to be integrated
integrand <- function(u, a, x) {
  denominator <- gamma(a - a * x) * gamma(a * x)
  numerator <- gamma(a)
  exponent <- a - a * x - 1
  result <- (numerator / denominator) * u^exponent * (1 - u)^(a * x - 1)
  return(result)
}

# Define the function representing the integral
integral <- function(x, y, a) {
  result <- integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = 1 - y, a = a, x = x)
  return(result$value)
}

# Define the partial derivative function
partial_derivative <- function(x, y, a, h = 1e-6) {
  (integral(x + h, y, a) - integral(x, y, a)) / h
}

# Test the partial derivative function
x <- 0
y <- 0.75
a <- 0.1
result <- partial_derivative(x, y, a)
print(result)
```

However, this seems to always result in an error when varying the values of `a` and `x`. The errors tend to vary which is why I am not posting it all, but here is an example:

```
Error in integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = y - 1, a = a, x = x) : 
  non-finite function value
```

I am hoping that it is something simple that somewhat can spot right away as I can't seem to find it. Likewise, I am open to other solutions for calculating equation (2) if there is a better solution.

Comment: What does this mean?  (What code was used?) “… this seems to always result in an error when varying the values of a and x. “

Comment: Just pick different values of a and x? I'm confused by your confusion.

Comment: The reasons for my confusion are partly answered by your comment on the more recent answer. I was looking for specific values that were problematic and how you were accomplishing the variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a beta distribution. Compare the following with your function:

```
integral_x <- function(x, y, a) pbeta(1 - y, a * (1 - x), a*x)

integral_x(x=0.1, y=0.2, a=0.3)
[1] 0.1288844
integral(x=0.1, y=0.2, a=0.3) # from your function above
[1] 0.1288844
```

The function gives exact results as your function. You can then carry out numerical differentiation on the `integral_x` function to obtain the needed derivative:

```
partial_dev <- function(x, y, a, h = 1e-4){
  (integral_x(x+h, y, a) - integral_x(x, y, a))/h
}

partial_dev(x = 0, y = 0.75, a = 0.3)
[1] 0.7043913
```

Comment: Thanks! I suppose the pbeta function is more stable than the one I wrote?

Comment: Actually for certain values I still get NaN where I wouldn't expect too based on figure 1 of the paper. For example, `x <- -2
y <- 0.75
a <- 0.1
integral_x <- function(x, y, a) pbeta(1 - y, a * (1 - x), a*x)
integral_x(x=x, y=y, a=a)` returns NaN which makes sense since a*x is negative but the beta distribution expects a positive value

Comment: @JohnSmith `x` cannot be negative. Note that the parameters alpha and beta for the beta function are strictly positive

Comment: I agree above x being positive, but if you look at Figure 1 in the paper, x goes from -3 to 3

Comment: Actually, you are correct, in their notation they are plugging in a positive quantity F_0(x)